# Account names are not getting listed when using apex:repeat

Tags: salesforce

This code works just fine for Contacts

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="contacts">
      <apex:pageBlock title="Contact Names">
        <apex:repeat value="{! contacts }" var="ct">
            <li>
              <apex:outputLink value="{! URLFOR($Action.Contact.Edit, ct.Id) }"> {! ct.FirstName } </apex:outputLink>
            </li>
        </apex:repeat>   
      </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

but almost identical code is not working for Accounts

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Account Names">
             <apex:repeat value="{! accounts }" var="a">
                <li> 
                 <apex:outputLink value="{! URLFOR($Action.Account.Edit, a.Id) }">  {! a.Name}  </apex:outputLink> 
             </li>    
        </apex:repeat>    
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Why is this happeneing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to output `{!filterId}` somewhere on the page (it'd correspond to [`getFilterId`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_methods.htm)).
See which listview it is. I expect it's a listview that has 0 results or "Recently Viewed" list (and it happens to be empty too). Or your user has no sharing permissions to see any accounts ;)

StandardSetController respects your last used listview. Select a good listview and refresh your page or view few random accounts.

If you want to display a specific listview you need something like https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_list_views.htm. Or you can pass view's Id as `fcf` parameter in the VF page's url.

Comment: Thanks. Clicking on  couple of accounts fixed the problem.